# Networking - In what scenarios do "RELATED" connections occur?

Tags: iptables

I am trying to use `iptables` and `ip6tables` to establish basic networking security on my webserver. However, I am having a hard time understanding the `RELATED` state of the `conntrack` module... I know that a packet is tracked as `NEW` when it is trying to establish a new connection, and as `ESTABLISHED` when it belongs to a previsouly established connection... But I really can't figure out under what situations a packet can be marked as `RELATED` (being that I know what the "definition" of `RELATED` means)... Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `RELATED` state means that the packet starts a new connection, but that connection is related to an existing connection. The classic example would be an FTP data connection that matches an existing FTP control connection.

This is most commonly used in NAT devices to permit incoming connections to work where existing outgoing connections make it clear which inside device the connection should go to. A classic example where this is needed is "no route to host" ICMP errors. They aren't part of an existing connection because they have a different source IP address.